# Can I sort a Microsoft Access report by number of records at the group level?

Tags: ms-access

I've created an Access report that is grouped by a person identifier and then displays all the rows in the source query related to that person identifier. I want to sort my report output by the person with the least number of rows to the person with the most number of rows. I can't use a GroupBy statement in the query because I have to display the detail records in the report. Hopefully this illustration helps.
[Image shows a table with personid and multiple data columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJfgS.png)

Comment: Maybe make an aggregate query that does the grouped count and join that query to report source table. Use that count to help sort records. Possibly cannot also group by person. Just sort and set textbox to not display repeated data. This a design issue and no code for review so question is not really suitable for SO.

Comment: Or use aggregate query as source for main report and a subreport for detail records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you can't use the GroupBy statement, does that mean you can't use the *Total* row in the Query Builder? (the reason I ask is because I've been able to achieve the same while still keeping the detail records)

So I made a replica of your table called **tbl_people** (and I added p# at the end of each field to make sure the data was going to the right area of the report) -close and save-

[image: tbl_people]

Then using the Query Builder, I added **tbl_people** and added `PersonID` ***TWICE.***
Click the totals button towards the top; then change the first column from Group By to `Count` and make the `Sort: Ascending` (and I ended up naming it qry_count) -close and save-

[image]

Make a report, Right click on the square in the corner, click on Report Properties,
[image]

Go to either the `Data` or `All` tab and click on the little three dots to the right of `Record Source`
[image]

Add **tbl_people** and **qry_count**. Then drag *PersonID* from **qry_count** to *PersonID* in **tbl_people** creating an equal join. Then add ALL fields from **tbl_people**, click totals (at the top of the Query Builder), set ID `Sort: Ascending`. Then from **qry_count** add field CountofPersonID and make sure that is in the front of the query builder

[image]

On your report, add the fields (I added all of them from the table) then with the Sorting/Grouping (the same way you find the Report Properties) add a `Group` and add a textbox in the header and make the `Control Source` the CountOfPersonID. And that should do the trick! :)

[image: Report design mode]

[image]

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out what you're describing. I haven't solved it but I've created a new table that includes a Count of the number of rows personID is in so I have that. maybe i can sort and then group.

Comment: I'll see if I can replicate it on a database for you

Comment: I created a group level sort on personID count and then was able to group by personID inside. It's not entirely successful.

Comment: Using using a group level based on count of person ID with a sub group level of person ID did a decent job of sorting by number of rows containing person ID. I'm new too. I'm sorry there was no VBA code but it was still a custom report in Access. I'm not sure why this was closed.

Comment: I just edited it! Let me know if this works for you! :)

Comment: That is very like what I ended up doing. I did a select into table query that included all the person source table data as well as the count of rows from the transaction table where their person ID appears. Then I created a new query using the new table for the report that included that row count for each person ID. In the report I created a group level for the count and then a group level for person ID. I was mostly able to sort by number of rows per person ID and saved myself a lot of time. Thanks for your help.